# How to use dsolve to return a real answer in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I tried this:

```
clear all
syms t real
assumeAlso(-1<t & t<1)
syms u(t)
sol2=dsolve(diff(u,t)==(2*t+sec(t)^2)/(2*u),u(0)==-5,t)
```

But it returns a complex answer.

[image]

Anyone have a way that this will return an answer with any i's in it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify one more initial condition in your `dsolve` function, otherwise you will always see the `t` variable in the solution. Once this is done, all you have to do is to add the following piece of code:

```
vpa(subs(sol2),2)
```

at the bottom of your current script.